# Sequences in $L_{p}(1<p<\infty)$ that is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{p}$ or $l_{2}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$. Johnson and Schechtman (Multiplication operators on $L(L_{p})$ and $l_{p}$-strictly singular operators, 2008, DOI: [10.4171/JEMS/141](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/141), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/277694), [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0560)) observed that if $(x_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence in $L_{p}$ that is equivalent to the unit vector basis for either $l_{p}$ or $l_{2}$, then $(x_{n})_{n}$ has a subsequence $(z_{n})_{n}$ which spans a complemented subspace of $L_{p}$. Is there a stronger result? More precisely,

Question: Does the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ have, for every $\epsilon>0$, a subsequence $(z_{n})_{n}$ which spans a $(1+\epsilon)C_{p}$-complemented subspace of $L_{p}$? where the constant $C_{p}$ depends only on $p$.

Thank you!

Comment: We did not suggest that the observation was due to us! It has been known for 40+ years.  The case that might not be in the literature, where $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $L_p$, $1<p<2$, that is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_2$, was shown to me by, I think, Pelczynski, and this was mentioned in our paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  Let $2<p<\infty$ and in $\ell_p \oplus_p \ell_2$ (which embeds isometrically into $L_p$) consider $x_n := e_n \oplus \alpha \delta_n$, where $(e_n)$; respectively, $(\delta_n)$, is the unit vector basis of $\ell_p$; respectively, $\ell_2$, and $0<\alpha <1$. One can show that the norm of any projection onto the closed span of any subsequence of $(x_n)$ is at least $M(\alpha,p)$, where $M(\alpha,p)\to \infty$ as $\alpha \downarrow 0$.  Maybe this is pointed out in Rosenthal's paper on the span of independent random variables in $L_p$.  It follows also from more general considerations in the complemented subspaces problem paper of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri.

You can build the same sort of example on the other side of $2$, reversing the roles of $p$ and $2$.

When $(x_n)$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_p$ and $2<p<\infty$, given any $\epsilon >0$ there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that spans a $1+\epsilon$-complemented subspace.  This is in Kadec-Pelczynski.

Something that I do not know at this moment and maybe never knew is whether a sequence in $L_p$, $1<p< 2$, that is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_2$ must have a subsequence that spans a $C_p$-complemented subspace of $L_p$.